# Conditional/Partitioned Running Total in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to create a new column called "new Value" that is the running total of an existing column - partitioned by several identifiers.

> x = 1 to 10
>
> _i_member reads off of an array {members} that has 24 items in it
>
> _i_simul  is the actual number of members in each item in the members array

Below is what members looks like:

```
array members {24} _temporary_ (5 6 8 10 12 15 20 25 30 40 50 
                                        60 70 80 90 100 125 150 175 200 250 300 400 500)
```

I tried using a data step:

```
data simulation_members3; 
        set claims.new_simulation_members;
        do until (last._i_member);
        by _i_member;
        New_Value + Value ;
end;
run;
```

But it doesn't work because the table isn't sorted by _i_member (_i_member = 1 repeats when x =2,3,..,24)
The first running total that is calculated should be the total of x=1 and _i_member=1, until it hits the last _i_simul value (which in the first value of the members array is 5, second value of members array is 6, etc.)

Here is what my current table looks like (called "claims.new_simulation_members")

```
     x |_i_member|_i_simul|     Value      | New Value
    ---|---------|--------|----------------|-----
     1 |      1  |   1    |     10         | 10
     1 |      1  |   2    |     15         | 25 = 10 + 15
     1 |      1  |   3    |     18         | 43 = 10 + 15 + 18  
     1 |      1  |   4    |     6          | 49 = 10+15+18+6
     1 |      1  |   5    |     8          | 57 = 10+15+18+6+8
     1 |      2  |   1    |     6          | 6
     1 |      2  |   2    |     7          | 14 = 6+7
   ... |    ...  | ...    |   ...          | ...   
    10 |      1  |   1    |     4          | 4
    10 |      1  |   2    |     5          | 9 = 4+5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this example

```
data test;
input member value;
datalines;
1 3
1 4
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
;
run;

proc sort data=test out=test_sorted;
by member;
run;

data test_sorted1;
    retain new_value;
    set test_sorted;
    by member;
    if first.member then new_value = value;
    else new_value + value;
run;
```